# Data is not fully shown in column chart chartkick and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts

So in my controller I have something like this

```
@datas = Data.find_by_sql("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(entry_date,'%d/%m/%Y') entry_date_disp, no_of_tests,
                                              no_of_issues,no_of_risks FROM datas
                                              WHERE company_id = " + current_dashboard_user.company_id.to_s + "  GROUP BY entry_date_disp")
```

and in my view I am trying to get all the tests , issues and risks grouped by date on my column chart

```
<%= column_chart @DataGovernances.map{|gov|
                                    {
                                       name: "Tests", data: {gov.attributes["entry_date_disp"]=>gov.attributes["no_of_tests"]},
                                       name: "Issues", data: {gov.attributes["entry_date_disp"]=>gov.attributes["no_of_issues"]},
                                       name: "Risks", data: {gov.attributes["entry_date_disp"]=>gov.attributes["no_of_risks"]}
                                    }
                    } ,stacked: true  %>
```

but it shows only the last mentioned data .

http://i.imgur.com/ZHqiwbO.png?1

I want the tests and Issues to be displayed as well

Comment: Idk if this will fix your issue, but I would rewrite the sql as:
"... WHERE company_id = '#{current_dashboard_user.company_id}' GROUP BY..."
Injecting the ruby this way auto makes it into a string so you don't need a to_s. Also keep in mind I'm still wrapping quotes around the company I'd as this is what SQL whats. Might not fix your issue, but will help not bring up any further issues.

Comment: Thanks i found the solution will post the answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the controller part and the added in the view like this

```
<%= column_chart @DataGovernances.map{|gov|
                                    {
                                       name: "Tests",     DataGovernance.where(company_id: current_dashboard_user.company_id.to_s).group(:entry_date).sum(:no_of_tests)}
like the same for the rest 
                                    }
                    } ,stacked: true  %>
```

this fixed the issue for me